# Swapping out boot drive without affecting D drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I need to change my boot hdd (C) to an ssd but most of my documents are stored on the D drive wich i will not remove from the system. Can i just replace the C with the ssd and install windows and the D drive would still work?

Comment: You would have to reconfigure your installation to use the drive obviously unless you just cloned the installation to the ssD.

Comment: I know, but would the D drive still work or do i have to clone that one as well?

Comment: That entirely depends on if you have 2 physical drives or 2 partitions on a single drive.

Comment: Ah my bad, they are diffrent drives. no partitions

Comment: If that is the case see my original comment.

Answer (score 1):

The new windows installation on your SSD will assign a drive letter to your second disk **(D:)** according to its [general order of drive letter assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive_letter_assignment) but it will be accessible.

*Make sure you don't format it.*

If the new installation assigns a drive letter other than **D:**, then you can always change it following the instructions below

[image]

Source : http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/change-add-remove-drive-letter